# Do I need the Ninject.Web.Mvc library in my application in order to use Ninject in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I downloaded the Ninject.Web.Mvc module and noticed that it did not contain the NinjectHttpApplication class which I discovered was in the Ninject.Web.Common and I have been using Ninject.Web.Common without the Ninject.Web.Mvc module and its been working well so far.
So my question is.. do I need the Ninject.Web.Mvc library in order to use Ninject properly in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application? I wouldnt want to add an assembly/library that I would not use in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ninject.Web.Mvc` module gives you the ability to add dependency injection on your controllers. If you don't need to have dependencies on the controller contructors, you can get by without this library.

Read more [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc#readme).

Comment: It does more than that.  It provides a lot of different MVC integration points, like filter injection.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I think I now get the picture

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you do not need it!

The not so short answer is still: No! But you'll need to make sure everything is handled correctly yourself, like wiring up the dependency resolver etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not *required*, but it does make your life easier.  This library has the glue to hook up your MVC app, and how to take advantage of things filter injection.

It's not required you use it, but not using it means you have to write a lot of code yourself.